# Making app to use for certain duration of time

Tags: android, countdown

I'm newbie to android I'm creating a quiz app . I need to make changes in  quiz app to used for certain duration of time for users after that it should say session expired.

I'm creating a quiz app . opening the app will open main activity which takes the user id and compares with the one in array. If it is true . it proceeds to next activity c1Activity in which question will be asked and user need to enter answer which is equated with stored value from array . if it is correct the user is proceeded to next question . similarly it go on until last question . my need is that the user should answer all questions within 3minutes if he lags the app should open a activity which shows times up

Comment: Hi, this is *extremely* vague. Can you add more detail about what you want to achieve - is this for *all* users? Does your app load data from a central server? When should the session start and expire? Also, please add the right tags - `android` being the most important

Comment: I'm creating a quiz app . opening the app will open main activity which takes the user id and compares with the one in array. If it is true . it proceeds to next activity c1Activity in which question will be asked and user need to enter answer which is equated with stored value from array . if it is correct the user is proceeded to next question . similarly it go on until last question  . my need is that the user should answer all questions within 3minutes if he lags the app should open a activity which shows times up .

Comment: Can you edit that into the question?

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution I can think for this is to implement a class that extends [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

First, you implement the class:

```
 class MyTimer extends CountDownTimer{

    // first param is the total amount of time it will countdown
    // second param is to fire onTick() method, in case you need to fire an alert or something
    public CountDown(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        //You can fire a Toast from here indicating how much time is left
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        //You can start the new activity from here
    }
 }
```

Finally, you just have to create and start an object of this class:

```
//3 minutes = 3 * 60 * 1000 
new MyTimer(180000, 1000).start();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.